# Adding the preface to contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to add the preface to the contents along with the page on the far right.

I had written it as following:

```
\chapter*{Preface}
```

but it does not appear on the contents.
If I write it as

```
\chapter{Preface}
```

then it would be the first chapter of the book and I don't want this at all...

How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which document class are you using?

Comment: the book document

Comment: Something like `\addtotoc{chapter}{Preface}` should do it. [Edit, sorry, this is a macro, see karlkoeller for the correct answer.]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add the line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
```

Just after

```
\chapter*{Preface}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want a different alignment like this one

[image]

use instead

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Preface}
```

Comment: @karlkoeller I personally had to use `\protect\numberline{~}` to make sure the alignment went through. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 7):

I'd modify `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to do continuous (arabic) numbering and exploit the fact that chapters are not numbered in the `\frontmatter`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmatterfalse}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

A preface

\chapter{Abstract}

An abstract.

\chapter{Introduction}

An introduction.

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

It's much easier than remembering to add `\addcontentsline`.

[image]