# Customizing bibliography style with back referencing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I want to put a full stop at the end of each bib item before the subscripted page numbers directed to the citations. For example, it appears as:

```
[1] Vladimir I Arnold. Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics. Vol. 60. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013 (p. 2)
```

I like to show it as:

```
[1] Vladimir I Arnold. Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics. Vol. 60. Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013. (p. 2)
```

I want to configure it such that clicking the page number in `(p. 2)` would take the pdf viewer to the specific citation point on page `2`.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \input{setup/preamble}
% basics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black},
    % backref=true, 
    % pagebackref=true
}

% Page Margins
\usepackage[
    margin=2.8cm, 
    % top=2.8cm, bottom=2.8cm,
    % left=1in, right=1in, 
    % headheight=14.5pt
    ]{geometry}

% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% bibliography
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    backref=true, 
    style=numeric, 
    sortcites=true, 
    sorting=none, 
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}       % bibliography  % https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_biblatex
\usepackage{xurl}                % handling the urls in bib file and it should be loaded after loading biblatex 

%% Change formatting of back references % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606518/114006
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
   backrefpage={p.},
  % backrefpage={},
   backrefpages={pp.}
  % backrefpages={
}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% \DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\mkbibparens{#1\addperiod}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
\xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{backrefparens}{}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@book{arnold2013mathematical,
  title = {Mathematical {{Methods}} of {{Classical Mechanics}}},
  author = {Arnold, Vladimir I},
  date = {2013},
  series = {Graduate {{Texts}} in {{Mathematics}}},
  volume = {60},
  publisher = {{Springer Science \& Business Media}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib} 

\title{Lecture Notes}
\author{me}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thepage{Title}
\maketitle
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}              
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% start lectures
\chapter{Sat, Mar 18, 2023}

\lipsum[1] \cite{arnold2013mathematical} 
\lipsum \cite{arnold2013mathematical} 

% \intput{endpage}

% Bibliography
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc, title={\protect\numberline{}Recommended Resources}] % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222961/114006
\printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Books}] % https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Getting_started_with_BibLaTeX
\printbibliography[nottype=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Others}]

\end{document}
```

Initially, I wanted to attach the back referencing link with the bib label too. But I realized it doesn't make sense as there can be situations when the same bib item is cited multiple times.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606518/114006

Comment: If adding back-ref to the bib labels is possible, what would happen when the same bib item is cited multiple times? In that case, where the back-ref would direct from the bib label? Is it even sensible to have such a back-ref style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can fix the final dot by re-inserting it after you suppressed it with `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}`.

I changed your `\DeclareFieldFormat` to:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{backrefparens}{\unskip.~\raisebox{-4pt}{\scriptsize{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
```

...and it *seems* to work.

[image]

About linking back the number, I think it should be possible, but probably it will link to the last citation... so I agree it's better as it is now.

**For the second question**, that seems a duplicate of [Precise back-reference target with hyperref and backref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54541/precise-back-reference-target-with-hyperref-and-backref) (but beware, that's a quite old answer, and `hyperref` changed a lot lately; so there could be a better way and/or the answer could or could not work).

Comment: Thank you. Currently, it's returning to the page. I like to take it to the exact citation point/location.

Comment: Ah. Two issues in one question again. . I am not sure if it's possible; the manual explicitly says that "it saves the backref *page*".  But this is more in the knowledge field of @UlrikeFischer...

Comment: But maybe this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54541/precise-back-reference-target-with-hyperref-and-backref is exactly the issue here?

Comment: Yes, that's the same issue!